# No provider exception when instantiate Validator using Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory() in quarkus application?

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, hibernate-validator

I have used custom api for validations which instantiated validator by Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator() in quarkus based application but application throw NoProviderFoundException with below error message

```
Caused by: javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
```

Quarkus has Hibernate Validator by default, but in my quarkus application with version 3.4.1 (Hibernate Validator-8.0.1-Final is by default dependency lib added by quarkus), the Hibernate Validator is not getting instantiated properly

I have run the same application with older quarkus version with 2.8.2 and it instantiated Hibernate Validator without issue

Confirmed the Hibernate validator by using below log

```
INFO  [org.hib.val.int.uti.Version] (Quarkus Main Thread) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.3.Final
```

I need to properly instantiate Hibernate Validator to run my application. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates misuse:

```
javax.validation
```

You're not using the right version of Bean Validation. The right version uses packages starting with `jakarta.validation`. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0#jakarta-ee-10

You need to use Jakarta Validation (`jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`), and align on the version that Quarkus provides ([`3.0.2` for Quarkus 3.4.1](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.4.1/bom/application/pom.xml#L83)).

I'd also suggest using the automated tool to migrate to Quarkus 3, see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0#automatic-update-tool

Comment: Since my dependency uses below code to instantiate validator and I could not change this code since it is from third party dependencies. is there anyway to allow my dependencies use javax.validation?

private static final javax.validation.Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
   .getValidator();

Comment: The best way would be to upgrade that dependency to a version that uses current technologies. Other than that, your only solutions will be dodgy ones, like using tools to transform the bytecode of that dependency to convert it to Jakarta Validation, e.g. [using Eclipse Transformer](https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-use-the-eclipse-transformer-project-to-convert-a-3rd-party-library). Depending on the license of that dependency, that may be illegal, though, so check the license. I can't help you further with that.